How can I run the parser and the telegram bot at the same time?
So that the parser constantly collects data in the database, and the bot accesses this database by commands?
There is a bot that works perfectly with the database, and there is a parser that collects data into this database. It is necessary that the parser is started at the start of the bot, but at the same time they interact only with the database at the same time, and work independently.
BOT:
from aiogram import Dispatcher, Bot, F
import asyncio
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from aiogram.client.bot import DefaultBotProperties
from aiogram.enums.parse_mode import ParseMode

# Подключаем роутеры
from gis.gis import gis_pars
from handlers.profile.profile import profile_router, process_pre_checkout_query, success_payment
from handlers.search_org.search_org import search_router
from handlers.add_organization.add_organization import create_route
from handlers.history_search.history_search import history_router
from handlers.mailing.mailing import mailing_route
from handlers.start.start import start_router
from handlers.view_user.view_user import view_router

load_dotenv()
token = os.getenv('TOKEN_ID')
bot = Bot(token=token, default=DefaultBotProperties(parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML))
dp = Dispatcher()


async def start_bot(bot: Bot):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=*****, text='****')
    await gis_pars()

# Регистрируем роутеры
dp.startup.register(start_bot)
dp.include_router(start_router)
dp.include_router(profile_router)
dp.include_router(search_router)
dp.include_router(create_route)
dp.include_router(history_router)
dp.include_router(mailing_route)
dp.include_router(view_router)

dp.pre_checkout_query.register(process_pre_checkout_query)
dp.message.register(success_payment, F.successful_payment)


async def start():
    try:
        await dp.start_polling(bot, skip_updates=True)
    finally:
        await bot.session.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(start())



PARS
`import asyncio
from selenium.common import StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from database.Database import DataBase
from gis.pathes import *

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

async def gis_pars():
    global main_block, main_banner, cookie_banner, items_count, phone_btn, next_page_btn, address, title, description, phone, link_org, category, link
    db = DataBase()
    
(next comes the code the working code of the parser)

 def main():
        asyncio.run(gis_pars())

 if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
`

I've tried many options, and either one or the other works, but not simultaneously and independently.

maybe you could use system/shell to start two programs at the same time. You can use & to run in background, and then you can start next program: python bot.py & and python parser.py

One approach to achieve this is by using multithreading. Multithreading allows you to run two separate pieces of code at the same time.
In this scenario, you could create one thread to run the bot and another thread to refresh information (database).
This way, both tasks would appear to run simultaneously.
It is important to know that using multithreading can cause potential conflicts if the bot modifies the data or interacts in some way with the database, which may not be up-to-date. To avoid these issues, you will need to properly synchronize access to shared resources between the two threads.
Python provides a threading module for creating and managing threads.
Example:
import threading

# Dummy Test Function
def bot_start_function(dummy_arg):
    print(dummy_arg)

# Creating the different Threads
bot = threading.Thread(target=bot_start_function, args=(5,))
database = threading.Thread(target=database_start_function)

# Starting the Threads
bot.start()
database.start()

For more information, you can see the documentation: Threading-Documentation
